# How can I link two pages through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I created two webpages and I want to connect them...except through JavaScript (I know how to do it in HTML) the first page is supposed to act almost like a password screen to prevent under aged users from entering. I have created a rough code but I don't know how to make them link properly. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<!-- this is how you add a code comment-->
<title> Entrance Page </title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#CEF6F5">

<form>

<h2 align=center><u> Please fill out the following information to proceed to the festival: </u></h2>

<br><br>First Name:<input type="text" name="First Name" id="first">    Last Name:<input type="text" 
name="Last Name" id="last">

<br><br> age:<select name="age" id="age">
<option value="1"> below 10 </option>
<option value="2"> 10 </option>
<option value="3"> 11 </option>
<option value="4"> 12 </option>
<option value="5"> 13 </option>
<option value="6"> 14 </option>
<option value="7"> 15 </option>
<option value="8"> 16 </option>
<option value="9"> 17 </option>
<option value="10"> 18 </option>
<option value="11"> 19 </option>
<option value="12"> 20 </option>
<option value="13"> above 20 </option>

</select>


</form>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<p align="center"> <button type="submit" onclick="run()"> Submit </button> </p>

<a href="Cost%20of%20an%20Event.html" id="pass"> </a>
<a href="Cost%20of%20an%20Event%20Entrance%20page.html" id="block"> </a>

<p><p id="p1">  </p>

<script>
    
    var firstName = document.getElementById("first").value 
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value
    var isNum = " ";
    
    isNum = isNum + isNaN(firstName)
    
    function run () {
        var firstName = document.getElementById("first").value 
        var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value
        if (age < 10 ) {
        window.alert("your too young to enter in this event!")//go back to Entrance page
    } else if (age > 10) {
        window.alert("welcome to the Oktoberfest website!");
        document.getElementById("pass").value//go to main website
    } else if (age == 10) {
        window.alert("lucky! you are just barely old enough to join!")
        document.getElementById("pass").value//go to main website
    }
}

    
    if (isNum == true) {
        window.alert("your name cannot be a number");    
    }//go back to Entrance page

    
    while (firstName.length ==0) {
        window.alert ("you didn't enter a first name ")
        document.getElementById("block").value//go back to Entrance page
        
    while (lastNamet.length ==0) {
        window.alert ("you didn't enter a last name ")
        document.getElementById("block").value//go back to Entrance page
        

</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```js
window.location.href = "your-next-page.html";
//or 
window.location.replace("your-next-page.html");
```

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, but my code still isn't working for some reason. do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: @BennetSchmidt what is the error you get?

Comment: @amar my submit button is not doing anything

Comment: Hello @BennetSchmidt, I tried editing your code to make it run -> https://jsfiddle.net/zqo5wvj0/5/.
The while loops in your script dont have closing braces, thus a syntax error. After adding the closing braces, it runs infinitely. I changed the while loops to ifs, since I believe you added the code for input validation.